# double to string with ostringstream syntax

Tags: c++, syntax, ostringstream

I'd like to understand why writing this

```
static_cast<std::ostringstream*>( &(std::ostringstream() << speed.x) )->str();
```

makes a string, but not this

```
(std::ostringstream() << speed.x).str();?
```

in fact the latter doesn't even compile...

I find this `static_cast<foo*>&foo` to be quite weird.

can you give me good examples in which case it's good practice to do so?

Comment: The reason you get an error is because the result of `(std::ostringstream() << speed.x)` is what the `operator<<` function returns, and it returns a reference to a `std::ostream`, which of course doesn't have a `str()` member function. In short, it's not really possible to do it as a one-liner. Why can't you use e.g. [`std::to_string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string) or [Boost lexical cast](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/doc/html/boost_lexical_cast.html)?

Comment: Tks for the answer, I tried `std::to_string`, but for an unknown reason codeblocks doesn't recognize it as a part of std even though I clicked -std=c++11.
Also, if as you say `<< operator` sends a reference to ostream, why would I need to use `&` again? Isn't it redundant?

Comment: You can cast a reference - no need to use pointers `static_cast<std::ostringstream&>( std::ostringstream() << x ).str() `

Answer (score 1):

The the expression `std::ostringstream() << speed.x` actually invokes the `operator<<(double)` on the underlying base class `std::ostream` interface.

The return type of `std::ostream::operator<<(double)` is `std::ostream&` which means you're trying to invoke the member function `std::ostream::str()` which of course does not exist. That method is on the derived class.

This is why the `static_cast` is necessary in this use case.

You could also write:

```
static_cast<std::ostringstream&>(std::ostringstream() << speed.x).str();
```

or since c++11

```
std::to_string(speed.x);
```

or in previous versions, you could write your own, less cryptic function which will do the same thing in a more maintainable way with no overhead.

```
std::string to_string(double x)
{
    std::ostringstream ss;
    ss << x;
    return ss.str();
}
```

Comment: if return type is `std::ostream&`, isn't it redundant to use & again? I mean this part: `&(std::ostringstream() << speed.x)`, isn't it like writing `&&foo` which is wrong, no?

Comment: @BenoîtLu if you wrote `static_cast<std::ostringstream>` then you'd be trying to take a copy of the `std::ostream`, which would result in a compile error.

Comment: Hmm... Are we clear that `std::ostream` is different than `std::ostream&` ? 
Return type of `std::ostringstream() <<` as you told me is `std::ostream&`, and in my snippet of code I have `static_cast<std::ostringstream*>&(std::ostream&)`. forget the static_cast, my problem is that we're doing `&(std::ostream&)`, so basically "getting a reference of a reference", that's what's bothering me, but it's working nonetheless. I hope I clarified my problem.

Comment: @BenoîtLu Careful. `&(x)` where x is a reference is taking the address of a reference, which is the same as taking the address of the object itself. It's not taking a reference of a reference. You could write `std::addressof(std::ostringstream() << speed.x)`